# How do I install node-oracledb behind a corporate firewall that blocks any public traffic?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, pcf

**Context**

I am trying to install node-oracledb module by running npm install oracledb for my project (behind corporate firewall). I have the proper proxies set! (y)

But its keeps throwing the following error:

**Yarn**

```
λ yarn add oracledb
yarn add v1.7.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<path>\test\test-oracle\node_modules\oracledb: Command failed.
Exit code: 87
Command: node package/oracledbinstall.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<path>\test\test-oracle\node_modules\oracledb
Output:
oracledb Beginning installation
oracledb Verifying installation
oracledb Continuing installation
oracledb ERR! NJS-054: Binary build/Release/oracledb.node was not installed.
oracledb ERR! Pre-built binary packages are not available for this version of Node.js (NODE_MODULE_VERSION="59")
oracledb ERR! Failed to install binary package oracledb-v2.3.0-node-v59-win32-x64.gz
oracledb ERR! connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.255.113:443
oracledb ERR! For help see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#troubleshooting
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

**npm**

λ npm install oracledb

```
> oracledb@2.3.0 install C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<path>\test\test-oracle\test-oracledb\node_modules\oracledb
> node package/oracledbinstall.js

oracledb Beginning installation
oracledb Verifying installation
oracledb Continuing installation
oracledb ERR! NJS-054: Binary build/Release/oracledb.node was not installed.
oracledb ERR! Pre-built binary packages are not available for this version of Node.js (NODE_MODULE_VERSION="59")
oracledb ERR! Failed to install binary package oracledb-v2.3.0-node-v59-win32-x64.gz
oracledb ERR! connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.255.113:443
oracledb ERR! For help see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#troubleshooting

npm WARN test-oracledb@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test-oracledb@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 87
npm ERR! oracledb@2.3.0 install: `node package/oracledbinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 87
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@2.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-11T19_17_03_152Z-debug.log
```

**RCA and Findings**

Upon looking at the `oracledbinstall.js` script that is responsible to get the module "installed", I could see one issue right away.

The script starts with the following:[image]

So I am fairly certain, when it tries to reach out to Github to grab the necessary binarie(s) and other scripts necessary for the oracledb module to run, it gets **blocked by my Firewall**.

**Resolution?**

So I would like to know if there is any way to successfully implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running `npm install oracledb` behind a corporate firewall. Configuring the certificates didn't help, but it worked when I put it in the same line. I also specified which binaries I needed when it gave this error:

```
oracledb ERR! Pre-built binary packages are not available for this version of Node.js (NODE_MODULE_VERSION="59")
oracledb ERR! Failed to install binary package oracledb-v2.3.0-node-v59-win32-x64.gz
. 
. 
.
npm ERR! oracledb@2.3.0 install: `node package/oracledbinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 87
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@2.3.0 install script.
```

**My Resolution:**

I was able to get it installed with this line:

`npm install --cafile "/path/to/myCA.cert" oracle/node-oracledb.git#v2.3.0`

I hope this would be able to help someone coming across this issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  It's time to upgrade to node-oracledb 4.0.0 !  The installer changed in 3.1 and it doesn't access github.  This should make it easier for some corporate uses

Answer (score 0):

- Read the [node-oracledb installation instructions](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instwin) about setting https_proxy - this is the 'proper' proxy, since any npm config proxy can't/won't be read by oracledbinstall.js.  Older npm's may also need http_proxy set.
- If your proxy needs authentication, then follow along or contribute to https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/pull/919
- If you can't get through your proxy, then read up on [Manually Extracting Pre-built Binaries](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#manualextraction)